# Image height and width when image not found

Tags: php, html, css

I have the following code:

```
<div>
  <img src="../images/curry.jpg" height="242" width="300" 
       alt="Can't find image (http://localhost/images/curry.jpg)">
</div>
```

I am trying to precisely lay out a page so, even if the image is not found, I would like the Alt text to occupy the given height & width.

1) is that now how HTML/CSS works?

2) if not, since I generating the HTML from PHP, is there anything I can do to achieve what I want? For instance, would it work if I check for non-existence and instead of an IMG tage, generate a Fieldset of the desired size, containing my Alt text?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer to you first question is Yes.
Alt attribute is for SEO purposes, and behaves as you have seen it.

It is possible although I must warn you of additional overhead,
there is a function [file_exists()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) to check if the image is existent.

If that function returns false instead of echoing the image just echo
"`<p>Can't find image (http://localhost/images/curry.jpg)</p>`"
and add a style attribute to the wrapping div that states your desired width and height

```
<div style='height: 242px;width: 300px'>
```

Comment: For what it's worth, you can easily style your `<img>` to be `display:block` or `display:inline-block` and apply the width and height to it.  It's just that the default display is `inline`, so the width/height are ignored when it falls back to being a non-replaced element.

Answer (score 1):

If you're generating the page using PHP you can just fix the width / height of the div.

As for the "Alt Text" could you show a small screenshot of what you want? I don't really understand by what you mean by occupying the given size.

Comment: +1 for replying. Thanks. I mean that I wanted the alt text "Can't find image (http://localhost/images/curry.jpg)" to occupy an area of 242 X 300 pixels.

Answer (score 0):

What happens when the browser can't find the image depends on the browser. Just have a look at this in a few browsers and see what happens:

http://jsfiddle.net/nhHyC/

Safari uses the specified dimensions but displays the "broken image" icon in that space.

Firefox 4 uses the `alt` text but ignores the dimensions.

Opera and Chrome use the specified dimensions and display the `alt` text in that space.

I didn't bother checking IE because those machines are hidden in the closet of my testing labs :)

If you need specific behavior then you'll have to do it yourself with a wrapper `<div>` with `display:inline-block` and the desired dimensions. Arranging the appropriate content will be trickier if you want to cover all the browsers.

The [`alt` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html40/struct/objects.html#h-13.8) is meant for user agents that cannot display images (such as screen readers and text only devices):

> For user agents that cannot display images, forms, or applets, this attribute specifies alternate text.

Comment: For what it's worth, the Firefox behavior also depends on quirks vs standards mode and a few other things...

Comment: @Boris: I was a little surprised that Firefox didn't behave more sensibly; OTOH, I was checking things with jsfiddle.net so I didn't have full control over the doctypes. I'd call the Opera and Chrome behavior the most sensible but reality has little to do with sense.

Comment: Oh, Firefox behaves completely sensibly.  In standards mode, if the image can't be loaded it's treated just like a `<span>` with the alt text inside.  The layout then just depends on the styles that are applied to it; that gives the page author full control over what exactly it is they want to happen.  If your `<img>` is `display:inline` then of course it'll ignore the width/height.  If it's `display:inline-block`, then it will use the given sizing.  Which one you want is totally up to you; there are use cases for both.

Comment: @Boris: Do you have an official reference for the default `display` value for `<img>`? I thought it was `inline-block` rather than `inline` but I've been wrong before and I'd be happy to be corrected if I'm wrong this time.

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#display-prop says `Initial: inline`.  So the display of everything is `inline` unless styled otherwise by some stylesheet (author, user, or user-agent).  The default stylesheets for typical UAs don't change the display value of `<img>`.  You can check this in any browser, actually, by just creating a page with `<img>` on it and looking at what `getComputedStyle` returns for `display`.